# Can the Apple Id be used by non Apple applications?

Tags: acs, federated-identity, federation, apple-id

Both Google and Facebook can act as Identity Providers in a security federation setup like Ping Identity or Microsoft ACS.

Does anyone know if it is possible to add Apple Id as an identity provider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After investigating sources over at apple.com and google, I must conclude that this is not possible now.

Hopefully, Apple will become and OpenID provider soon.

Comment: Apple is using Google Apps (google.com/a/) . Unfortunately this makes all the @ me.com and @mac.com OpenID but only the Apple employees can take advantage of it.

Comment: Good to know. I would still love to allow my customers use the Apple ID to login to my services

Comment: Things are happening here. 2.5 years after I asked about this: http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/11/03/apple-activates-single-sign-on-for-tvos-and-ios-beta-testers

Answer (score 3):

Apple does not currently provide an API through which one can use AppleID or iCloud as an identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

[Sign in with Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210318) has been implemented and [developer documenation](https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/get-started/) is available. It supports authenticating [website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/configuring_your_webpage_for_sign_in_with_apple) and [application](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/incorporating_sign_in_with_apple_into_other_platforms) users by their Apple ID.

> Sign in with Apple allows you to set up a user account in your system, complete with name, verified email address, and unique stable identifiers that allow the user to sign in to your app with their Apple ID. It works on iOS, macOS, tvOS, and watchOS. You can also add Sign in with Apple to your website or versions of your app running on other platforms. Once a user sets up their account, they can sign in anywhere you deploy your app.
>
> Sign in with Apple is not available for children under 13 years old. This age may vary by country or region.

[Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-apple-id?pivots=b2c-user-flow) (Preview as of Mar, 2021) supports Apple ID. (Side note that you can also do the reverse: [using AD to sign into Apple](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment-reference-ios/integrating-with-azure-ad-apd86739b87e/web)).

[Ping has explicit support](https://www.pingidentity.com/en/integrations/apple.html) for Sign in with Apple.

Answer (score -2):

Of course not. Apple servers for users are private for their users only, which means other identify services such as facebook or google, don't work with apple servers. Then it's not possible.

Comment: "Apple servers for users are private for their users only"
That's actually the opposite of what having Apple as an Identity Provider would do. It would not give access to Apple's servers, but it would give access to apple users to other servers using the same credentials they use with Apple.